# transform two xml based on xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to dynamically transform between two xml based on the xpaths.
E.g.
I have source xml which looks like:

```
<Source>  
 <ZeroLine>
   <FirstLine>
     <Name>Name1</Name>
     <SurName>SurName1</SurName>
   </FirstLine>
   <FirstLine>
     <Name>Name2</Name>
     <SurName>SurName2</SurName>
   </FirstLine>
 </ZeroLine>
 <ZeroLine>
   <FirstLine>
     <Name>Name3</Name>
     <SurName>SurName3</SurName>
   </FirstLine>
   <FirstLine>
     <Name>Name4</Name>
     <SurName>SurName4</SurName>
   </FirstLine>
 </ZeroLine>
</Source>
```

I need to transform this source xml to the target xml, which can have different structure. This target xml structure is builded based on the xPath.

The target xml can looks e.g. like this:

```
<Target>
  <TargetZeroLine>
    <TargetFirstLine>
      <NameIdentifikator>Name1</NameIdentifikator>
      <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName1</SurNameIdentifikator>
    </TargetFirstLine>
    <TargetFirstLine>
      <NameIdentifikator>Name2</NameIdentifikator>
      <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName2</SurNameIdentifikator>
    </TargetFirstLine>
  </TargetZeroLine>
  <TargetZeroLine>
    <TargetFirstLine>
      <NameIdentifikator>Name3</NameIdentifikator>
      <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName3</SurNameIdentifikator>
    </TargetFirstLine>
    <TargetFirstLine>
      <NameIdentifikator>Name4</NameIdentifikator>
      <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName4</SurNameIdentifikator>
    </TargetFirstLine>
  </TargetZeroLine>
</Target>
```

The XPath rules for this example are:

Source XPath -> Target Xpath

Source/ZeroLine/FirstLine/Name -> Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine/NameIdentifikator

Source/ZeroLine/FirstLine/SurName -> Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine/SurNameIdentifikator

I have only source xml(xsd) and these xpaths rules and I need to dynamically build xslt transformation which will create target xml.

I can write this xslt manually and it works like I want, but I need to build it dynamically based on different xPaths rules. For this example xslt transformation looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Source">
    <xsl:element name="Target">         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ZeroLine"/>            
    </xsl:element>                  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ZeroLine">
    <xsl:element name="TargetZeroLine"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstLine"/>
    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FirstLine">
    <xsl:element name="TargetFirstLine">            
        <xsl:element name="NameIdentifikator">
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        </xsl:element>                  
        <xsl:element name="SurNameIdentifikator">
            <xsl:value-of select="SurName"/>
        </xsl:element>                  
    </xsl:element>                  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And what is my problem? :) The problem is how to build the xslt for target from xPath. I can write this template manually when I know how the target xml should look like.

E.g. I can write manually xslt template for this XPath:

```
Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine/NameIdentifikator
```

it is:

```
<xsl:template match="FirstLine">
    <xsl:element name="TargetFirstLine">            
        <xsl:element name="NameIdentifikator">
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>                 
                    </xsl:element>            
    </xsl:element>                  
</xsl:template>
```

But how can I write C# code which will dynamically generate this xslt? Because I don't know which   xsl:element... should I generate to which templates.

Or the question can be also: is it possible to write xslt xsl:element based on xPath? I mean something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="FirstLine">
    <xsl:element name="Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine">          
        <xsl:element name="NameIdentifikator">
```

I hope, that my question will be clear for understanding.

## UPDATE1

The XPath rules can be different between source and target. Also level of the hierarchy can be different. E.g. the following XPath rules:

```
Source/ZeroLine/FirstLine/Name -> Target/NameSection/NameIdentifikator
Source/ZeroLine/FirstLine/SurName -> Target/SurNameSection/SurNameIdentifikator
```

should produce the following expected xml:

```
<Target>
<NameSection>
    <NameIdentifikator>Name1</NameIdentifikator>
    <NameIdentifikator>Name2</NameIdentifikator>
    <NameIdentifikator>Name3</NameIdentifikator>
    <NameIdentifikator>Name4</NameIdentifikator>
</NameSection>
<SurNameSection>
    <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName1</SurNameIdentifikator>
    <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName2</SurNameIdentifikator>
    <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName3</SurNameIdentifikator>
    <SurNameIdentifikator>SurName4</SurNameIdentifikator>
</SurNameSection>
</Target>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to select element name, just overlap your query with `{}`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:element name="{Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine/NameIdentifikator}">
```

Comment: When I'm using this approach I'm getting error: '' is an invalid QName. My xslt looks like: <xsl:template match="FirstLine">
    <xsl:element name="{Target/TargetZeroLine/TargetFirstLine/NameIdentifikator}"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are over-complicating things here. Looking solely at your input XML and output XML, then one way to write the XSLT stylesheet would be as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Source">
    <Target>     
        <xsl:apply-templates />            
    </Target>                  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ZeroLine">
    <TargetZeroLine> 
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </TargetZeroLine>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FirstLine">
    <TargetFirstLine>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />              
    </TargetFirstLine>                  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
    <NameIdentifikator>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />              
    </NameIdentifikator>                  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SurName">
    <SurNameIdentifikator>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />              
    </SurNameIdentifikator>                  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, it doesn't really worry about the hierarchical structure or position of the elements. There is simply a template for each separate element you wish to rename.

As you can probably see, this leads to each template having the same structure.

```
<xsl:template match="### INPUT ELEMENT ###">
    <### OUTPUT ELEMENT ###>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />              
    </### OUTPUT ELEMENT ###>                  
</xsl:template>
```

So, if you did really want to write some C# to generate the XSLT for you, you could simply define a constant with placeholders, like so

```
public const string TEMPLATE = @"<xsl:template match="{0}">
    <{1}>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />              
    </{1}>                  
</xsl:template>";
```

Then, assuming you had some way of linking source element names to target element names, you could just do something like this

```
output.WriteLine(string.Format(TEMPLATE, sourceElement, targetElement));
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. it looks much better. Could you please take a look on the UPDATE1 in my question and tell me if it is possible with your solution to realize also this case? the problem is, that the XPath rules may have different variations. thanks a lot.

Comment: No, I am afraid my solution wouldn't cover that, as it is a whole different transformation required. Ideally you should be asking a whole new question, rather than making updates to an existing question, otherwise the question will become too large and unwieldy. Thanks!